# Importing scripts into AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view as below:

```
<headers>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
</headers>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/some.css"/>

<script ng-src="js/my-view-script.js"></script>
```

However, when the view is loaded the script isn't fetched. I've also tried `<script src="js/my-view-script.js"></script>` and had the same trouble.

So, how do I load a script file for a single view only?

CHeers

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Try loading jQuery before AngularJS:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I remember seeing it somewhere that jqLite (which is used by Angular) doesn't support that.

Comment: This solution works for angular v1.0.7 but does not work for v1.2.0rc1. Have not found a workaround yet.